# Does the Fermi distribution also gives the probability of an energy level being full of electrons?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, probability, quantum-statistics, fermi-energy

We started to learn about Fermi level and Fermi distribution function and I'm little confused .
From what I have understood , the Fermi distribution function gives the probability of a single state in some energy level being full of electron . Then after that the teacher said (from how I understood) is that it also gives the probability of that energy level being full of electrons and here begins my confusion.
lets say a certain level has 5 sates and the Fermi distribution function gives that each state has the probability of 0.2 to be full of an electron, so what is the probability that the energy level is full of electrons ? is it also 0.2 or is it 0.2^5 (that's how I think it should be) ?
-thank you

Answer (score 1):

Fermi Dirac distribution is giving by the equation

$$
   f(E) = \frac{1}{1+ \exp\{ \frac{E-\mu}{K T}\}}
$$
Where $\mu$ is called the chemical potential. The propability of finding electron at $\mu$ is $1/2$. This gives the probability of finding an electron at energy $E$. Of course, another factor $D(E)$ indicates how many degenerate states at the energy $E$. For example, the total number of electron $N$ is:

$$
  N = \int_0^{\infty} D(E) f(E) dE. \tag{1}
$$

In fact, Eq.(1) is used to determine the chemical potential $\mu$. $\mu(T)$ is a function of temperature.

Eor example, assume that $F(E_1) = 0.2$. It  means  that the probability of finding an electron at energy level $E_1$ is 0.2. The average number of electrons having energy between $E_1 + dE$ and $E_1$ is eqaul to $N(E_1+dE) - N(E_1)= F(E_1) D(E_1) dE$.  $D(E_1) d E$ denotes the energy level degeneracy between $E_1+dE$ and $E_1$.  For 5 states, each one has probability 0.2, the average number of elctron in this energy will be 1. Since it is 1 electron in 5 states, each state still has probability 0.2.

In the extreme case $T=0 K$, the Fermi-Dirac distribution becomes a Heaviside step function, and the chemical potential is called Fermi level $\mu_F = \mu(T=0)$

$$
   f(E) = 0 \text{ for } E \gt \mu_F; \\
   f(E) = 1 \text{ for } E \lt \mu_F;
$$

Comment: Thanks you for the info but I'm still confused . From what you wrote ,the Fermi distribution  gives the " probability of finding an electron at energy level E" . So what does that exactly mean , does it mean the probability to find at least one state in level E full of an electron in or it is the probability that this energy level's states are all full of electrons  ?

Comment: For *each* level of energy $E$, the probability of this level being occupied is $f(E)$. This means if you have $10$ levels with $f(E) = 0.2$, $2$ levels will be occupied on average (the number of levels occupied follows a binomial distribution with $p = f(E) = 0.2$ and $N = 10$).

Comment: @NazareneChristianSoldier This is statistic. The probability 0.2 means that in 10 such systems, you will find 2 has one electron, and the rest of 8 is empty. In Statistic Mechanics, we call 10 ensembles, 2 have 1 electron, and 8 empty render an average 0.2.